# foreign key constraint not respected

Tags: mysql

I have recently switched jobs and at this new company we are using MySQL. I don't have any expereince with MySQL, although I have used SQL Server and Oracle for over 4 years now.
Now the strange thing I see with MySQL is that it does not seem to resepect some of the basic things like Foreign Key Constraints (meaning a column is a foregin key but i can insert any value here no matter if it's present in the other table where this FK related to). Now I know in SQL Server there is this concept of a NOCHECK foriegn key constraint but the guy at new company responsible for MySQL db say that not respecting a FK is a normal thing in MySQL and it does not need to have any special settings (like NOCHECK FK constraint).

I fail to understand that in a database system how can you ensure referential integirty without having these basic checks in place. I am not sure if the local mySQL "expert" know it well or it's just that mySQL really does not respect FK rules. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your tables are using the InnoDB engine. When using the MyISAM engine (which was the default until recently), foreign keys declarations are not enforced.

Comment: How can I check that? remember i am totally new to mySQL

Answer (score 2):

MySQL have different DB Engines -

- MyISAM - default, no FK support
- InnoDB - have FK support - but no fulltext search like in MyISAM

On both engines you can create table and try to create FK, but MyISAM will simply ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure foreign keys are being enforced. For some reason they weren't on mine, leading to one week of headache!

**Check:**

```
SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS
```

**Set:**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1
```